# Research paper abstract paragraph in Markdown

Tags: markdown

Is there a way to make a specially formatted paragraph in markdown, but without the css?

What is needed: a paragraph narrover on both sides by some margin (absolute or relative), preferably in italics and in a smaller font.

`<p width></p>` does not work.

Comment: No, Markdown is intentionally simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in regular Markdown.

If you're using something like Pandoc, then you might be able to specify an `abstract` variable in the frontmatter:

```
---
title: foo bar
abstract: >
  abstract goes here
---

the rest of the paper
```

Answer (score 0):

Markdown, by itself, does not have this facility.

Many Markdown implementations permit embedded HTML, so you might be able to use something like:

```
# Title

<blockquote>
<small><i>Introduction goes here</i></small>
</blockquote>

Rest of document
```